# What is the difference between accent and sforzando?

Tags: dynamics, cello, accent

In particular, on cello. I got the impression that both are strong (either by pressure or speed) at the beginning of the note, followed by quick release of pressure/speed. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Not necessarily - some sfz can be interpreted as "hit it strong and stay strong"

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the difference between ^ and >. Both signs are used as accents in generally. The correct designations are *marcato* (>) and *martellato* (^).

Usually *marcato* means **accentuated** and *martellato* means **strong accentuated**. So you see that there is only a small difference. And it is often discussed how exactly these two accents are played differently and in particular with a certain instrument (like in your case a cello).

However sforzato and/or sforzando (*sf* and *sfz*) are dynamics. They are dynamics and mean **with sudden emphasis** in the sense of sudden change of the volume.

So summarizing: accents like ^ and > are similar to dynamic instructions like sforzando and sforzato, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

A sforzando(sfz) is the loudest and strongest accent. It is not really considered a dynamic as another answer suggests.